# ActionView is missing template in Preview. How to resolve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am currently trying to have ActionMailer send an email with Letter_Opener gem. When I try to view the preview with `localhost:3000/mailer/order_mailer` the terminal logs this error:

```
app/mailers/order_mailer.rb:10:in `new_order_email'
Started GET "/rails/mailers/order_mailer/new_order_email" for ::1 at 2023-01-27 16:27:38 -0800
Processing by Rails::MailersController#preview as HTML
  Parameters: {"path"=>"order_mailer/new_order_email"}
OrderMailer#new_order_email: processed outbound mail in 1.2ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms (Allocations: 9119)
  
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template order_mailer/new_order_email with "mailer".

Searched in:
  * "order_mailer"
):
```

**app/mailer/order_mailer.rb**:

```
class OrderMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'actionMailerTester2301@gmail.com'

  # layout "order_mailer"
  
  def new_order_email
    @email = 'joeDANE@example.com'


    mail(to: @email, subject: "Thank you for your donation.")

  end
end
```

On the browser, the `mail(to:.....` line is pointed out. I've looked through multiple stackoverflow entries and I can't figure it out, though I chalked it up to my unfamiliarity with Ruby to not being about to understand the problem.

I'm hoping if I can figure out why the preview isn't working that I'll figure out the secondary problem with the Letter Opener gem.

Comment: They exist in `app/mailers/views/order_mailer`. Should I change `layout: mailer` to `layout: mailer/views/order_mailer`?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails prefers following certain conventions over configuration. In most cases, it is much easier and straight-forward to just follow the Rails' way instead of over-customizing your application.

In this specific example, I suggest to not change or re-configure where Rails finds the mailer views, but to just place the views in the default folder.

Following the conventions, for the mailer views and how your mailer and its method is named, the views should be named and located like this in the `app/views` folder (not in `app/mailers/views`):

```
app/views/order_mailer/new_order_email.html.erb
app/views/order_mailer/new_order_email.text.erb
```

Read about [mailer view naming in the official Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#create-a-mailer-view).